# Angular 12 credentials reading from json file for login

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to implement login functionality by reading from json file?
NOTE: This is for an internal application so basic login functionality is enough.

```
{
    "credentials" : {
        "username" : "user1",
        "password" : "pass1"
    },
    {
        "username" : "user2",
        "password" : "pass2"
    },
    {
        "username" : "user3",
        "password" : "pass3"
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me through how to implement json file to auth service/login-component....any reference code would be much appreciated?

Thanks,

Comment: you need to provide more info, I think it's not related to angular, implementing authentication requires a backend, an endpoint like "/auth/login" where you'll send user credentials and server will match those against the credentials stored in your json file.

Comment: I don't want to use any backend server for authentication instead i want to have a json file where all credentials are stored and based on that login functionality should work! (this project is purely for our internal stuff so basic authentication is enough)

Comment: well in that case, you have two ways: directly import json file or make an http call to load it whenever required, for first way you can just write something like `import data from "/assets/credentials.json"` and based on your provided json, data.credentials property will hold all your credentials or make an http call to fetch that json file, either way you can then loop over all credentials to check for authentication.